# Rename cell's text - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Is there anyway of renaming a specific cell's text? I know what the row number is, but I don't know how to change the cell title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = "new text";
```

Comment: What if it was a custom uitableviewcell? And I don't believe this code works. I have tried it but the name stays the same. I'm doing this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath... the value of the row is in an int variable.

Comment: I updated my answer a few times, so you should try it now.  You don't need this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method; that's where the cell itself is created.  If you want to change it later you should use this code elsewhere.

Comment: As for custom UITableViewCells, it depends on how the cell was created.  If it doesn't use the textLabel property to display its text, you will have to look at its implementation to determine how to update its content.

Comment: If the UITableViewCell cell does not immediately update its content you may need to call [cell setNeedsDisplay].

Comment: If you have a custom cell then you would cast the results of the callForRowAtIndexPath: to your particular type of cell, since that is what the table view will give you...

Comment: For a custom cell you can add your UILabels in the storyboard (inside the UITableViewController cell) and set their tags. Afterwards in the code you will use [cell viewWithTag:1]